# In App Purchase Packaging

Tags: ios, binary, in-app-purchase, package

First my question, then my situation:

Question: Can a new binary be used as an IAP? So instead of using the IAP feature to download say a weapon pack or a song, can it download a completely new binary of the same app, that way when the user upgrades they no longer have ads and they have additional features that weren't present in the free version.

Situation: As brief as possible, Apple has approved both my IAP package and my new free version for the public to have accessibility to upgrade. However, when trying to upgrade, after making the purchase (sandbox or live), nothing happens... the account gets debited the 99 cents, but the user never receives the paid version of the app. I'm assuming that there's an issue with the actual package.... which leads me to believe that Apple approved it without checking the integrity (perhaps it's not Apple's responsibility, but I figured that checking for a faulty IAP would be just as important as checking for crashes).

Am I on the right track about the packaging being faulty? Could it be something else? If doing a new binary is possible, is there documentation anywhere online about setting it up properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this all wrong. You can't provide an updated app as an IAP. Your free app with IAP must include all desired functionality built into it. When the user purchases a feature through IAP, the existing app uses that as a flag and simply starts letting the user use the additional feature(s) or to stop displaying ads.

Basically on startup your app checks to see if the user has made the in-app purchase or not. If not, you show ads and/or hide certain functionality. If they have, you don't show ads and you show the appropriate functionality.

Comment: I was afraid of this. Doing it that way is a bit of a pain since the paid version is reconstructed. So what would the IAP package contain? Some sort of string or token that says "I paid"? Thank you.

Comment: If this is a non-consumable IAP then there is no package.

Answer (score 0):

In-app purchases are there for products which on download can be used after purchasing. But in your case you are downloading the full version of the app on in-app purchase. Do you have any way to load binary of an app? No, right?

What you can do is just disable all functionalities of full version of the app through coding, when on purchase just enable all features for pro version.